# the phrase 'the Americans' - subtleties

Tags: nouns, definite-articles

'Americans,' when you refer to them generically, lots of times go without 'the.' In-depth research finds that 'Americans' without 'the' is perceived more as a nation that is driven by individuals; individual differences are felt more in the noun phrase.

My question is why do you think '**the** Americans' was chosen as the title for this photo collection: [The Americans](https://www.nga.gov/features/robert-frank/the-americans-1955-57.html). The photographer Robert Frank traveled around the nation, extensively depicting daily moments of America's men and women, boys and girls in 1955 and 1956. My take is that while the noun phrase 'the Americans' carries a sense of the nation as a whole, maybe a bit lessening the salience of the existence of individual differences, it covers **everyone** on the land of the United States - completeness, and so that he wanted to tell the audience his book is all-inclusive, inclusive of everyone, relying on the latter nature of the phrase 'the Americans.' Maybe he also wanted to have the title carrying the sense of 'individual differences,' but maybe he took the completeness aspect over the other.

Am I on the right track? Is my interpretation of 'the Americans' sufficient?

Comment: Sorry, I said just 'the American' here and there in the original. I corrected the mistakes. They should have been 'the Americans.'

Comment: No, you're *not* "on the right track". The difference made by including the definite article or not in such contexts is as per usual - it implicitly emphasises the "uniqueness / individuality" of ***the referent itself***. In this case, that means emphasising the uniqueness of ***Americans collectively*** (implying they're very different to any other nationality). It's got nothing to do with whether any *specific* American is any more or less of an "individual" than, say, a native of France or China (so a Frenchman is more like a Chinaman than he is like an American, by this logic).

Comment: Thank you very much, FumbleFingers. Yes, collectively. Emphasis is on the collective characteristics of the nation - more so than on individual differences within the nation, right? And I was wondering if 'the Americans' interprets as more complete than just 'Americans.' 'The  Americans' covers all the nation whereas 'Americans' covers most of the nation as a subtlety.

Comment: I think nowadays, "unarticled" ***Americans*** would almost always be understood to mean ***citizens of the USA*** (unlike ***the North / South Americans***, which would refer to inhabitants of those continental land masses collectively, regardless of nationality.

Comment: I observe a lot more 'Americans's than 'the Americans's to emphasize individuality amongst the people. The book would be more clearly perceived as one having a wide diversity of people and their day-to-day activities without 'the.' Thanks, FumbleFingers. Great help!

Comment: It's quite true that many people would agree with the general proposition that Westerners in general (and Americans = "citizens of the USA" in particular) promote the importance of the individual more than people from other regions. But that's not directly related to the matter of whether to attach an article to ***Americans*** as a plural noun - it's just a piece of relevant background "pop sociology".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My take is that while the noun phrase 'the Americans' carries a sense
> of the nation as a whole, maybe a bit lessening the salience of the
> existence of individual differences, it covers everyone on the land of
> the United States - completeness, and so that he wanted to tell the
> audience his book is all-inclusive, inclusive of everyone, relying on
> the latter nature of the phrase 'the Americans.'

Close.

A better reading, however, would be that "The Americans" refers to a collective ethnic "people" or political "nation" as a single concept, with certain discoverable characteristics that distinguish this "people" from another ethnicity, rather than to a collective group of specific people who could be counted up in a census. Also, it would not necessary include everyone in America. For example, it wouldn't include casual tourists from abroad.

The intent of the phrase is to conceptualize, and to invite the listener to define, this "People".

It is analogous to "the Jews" in the sense of the Jewish people, or "the Iroquois" in the sense of the Iroquois Indian Nation of Native Americans as a cultural and political people and nation, rather than as a legally defined entity.

But, the term "the Americans" in particular also carries a certain sense of irony or paradox to it that similar constructions would not, because unlike most ethnicities or nations or "peoples", "the Americans" is inherently defined as a diverse and multiethnic population. To some extent, using the term embraces the concept of America as a "melting pot" with some ultimate commonality that emerges from the different peoples who contribute to the whole, rather than a "mixing bowl" concept of America as a place where different groups of people merely happen to share territory and co-exist. In other words, "the Americans" implies that a process of ethnogenesis has occurred.